# Probability amplification for a randomised algorithm

Tags: algorithm, random, probability

I missed the lecture on randomised algorithms and can't wrap my head around amplifying the probability of a two sided error algorithm.

Can someone explain why the probability that the following algorithm gives a correct output increase through repetition and how can that probability be calculated?

L is a formal language
  If the input x ∈ L, the output of the algorithm will be YES with a probability of 2/3
If the input x !∈ L, the output of the algorithm will be NO with a probability > 1/2

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need a funky decision rule to crack this one. Run the algorithm `n` times, and if at least a 7/12 (= midway between 1/2 and 2/3) fraction of the outputs are YES, output YES.

The hand-wavy justification is that, for every NO input, the expected fraction of YES outputs converges by the law of large numbers to at most 1/2, and for every YES input, the expected fraction of YES outputs converges to at least 2/3. Formally, we have to invoke [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) or something equivalent, which shows that the probability of error decreases as `O(exp(-cn))` for some fixed constant `c`.

Comment: So we use a majority function to choose the answer. But how would you calculate the probability that answer is correct for n runs? Edit:  I got the notes of a classmate and this is what he wrote: (2/3)^3 + 3 · (2/3)^2 · 1/3 = 20/27 (for n = 3), but I still don't get how this works

Comment: @alpacaboi Hoeffding's inequality. We have to apply it twice, once for each tail.